# TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'West Africa Time' was not found on the local computer

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, asp.net-core-3.1, datetimeoffset

I have a transaction date stored in the database as DateTimeOffset UtcNow.
When I retrieve the date, I get something like the following

> 16/08/2020 9:12:34 PM +00:00

But I want to represent the time of transaction to represent the exact time in the timezone of UTC+1 which is where my client resides. But when I try to use the following code

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(item.TransactionTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time"));
```

I get the following error,

> TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'UTC+1' was not found on the local computer.

I have also tried

```
  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(item.TransactionTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("West Central Africa"));
```

Yet no luck.

What could I be getting wrong?

My application is on ASP.NET-Core 3.1 running on windows server.

Please help

Comment: "W. Central Africa Standard Time" seems to be a Valid timeZone Id.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values

Can you try TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() and see what values it has?

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara , I did that already and that was how i actually go that Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZoneInfo NaijaZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time");
```

I got it working using the code up there, although it was writing that error above as well but I think whitespace affected the ID.

Comment: What do you mean by "whitespace affected the ID"?

Comment: @KlausGütter I just thought of it because i have been getting same errors lately before it later works for me, and what have i noticed is that, if the compiler didnt get the actual zone as the inbuilt timezones, it will prompt out error. I tried "W.central....", "West Centra...." until i debug and copied the actual zone. so when i used the zone i copied, it works